# Cassandra unknown exception

Tags: cassandra

I have managed to set up [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/) + [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) and the Python wrapper for Thrift [LazyBoy](http://github.com/digg/lazyboy), and I have followed an [example](http://github.com/digg/lazyboy/tree/master/examples) mentioned in the LazyBoy Wiki.After testing that example I'm getting an error with an exception.

```
cassandra.ttypes.InvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why='Keyspace
UserData does not exist in this schema.')
```

here's the exception.I'm expecting some helping hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the keyspace 'UserData' exists in your configuration file (conf/storage-conf.xml)

E.g

```
<Keyspaces>
    <Keyspace Name="UserData">
     ....
</Keyspaces>
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, do this configuration need to be done every time when a new keyspace is created.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the comparison but you could compare a keyspace to a database name.

Comment: Note to reader, I'm looking to answer this question, although the answer here may be a bit dated.  Prior to the 0.7 release, Cassandra storage configuration is described by the conf/storage-conf.xml file. As of 0.7, it is described by the conf/cassandra.yaml file.  (see top of this page: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration)

Answer (score 2):

For those just starting out with Cassandra/Pycassa then maybe you've been working through [this tutorial](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/tutorial.html) and you get stuck on the line

```
col_fam = pycassa.ColumnFamily(pool, 'Standard1')
```

with an error that looks like

```
pycassa.cassandra.ttypes.InvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why='Keyspace Keyspace1 does not exist')
```

To resolve this, start Cassandra

```
bin/cassandra -f
```

And then in another terminal window load the sample schema using

```
bin/cassandra-cli -host localhost --file conf/schema-sample.txt
```

Then you should make it past that line in the tutorial.